# Java/Scala streaming timeseries data

Tags: java, streaming, messaging, netty

I've got underlying timeseries database based on HBase (OpenTSDB), on top of it works my applications that somehow loads data from HBase. I need to stream this fetched time series to application clients. What is the best solution for it? If client paused processing already received data, server should also pause, if client dead, server should stop sending data.

I would like a pure Java solution. I know about ZMq, but had not very nice experience with it. Maybe I should take a look on Netty?

P.S. Amount of data is big enough. Gigabytes and tens of gigabytes per one request to server.